# Acumatica PXGrid PXDropDown value changing does not update the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Cache notified about the modification of the field in the row, only when grid row selection is changed.
I have a grid with one editable record in the row: KiwiSaver status:
[image]
I added validation error and control enabled/disabled state of "save & export" button in the event `row_selected`:

```
    protected virtual void MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem;

        if (row.IsNull()) return;

        AllEmployeesTransactions.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem.kiwiSaverStatus>(
            row, row.KiwiSaverStatus,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.KiwiSaverStatus)
                ? new PXSetPropertyException("KiwiSaver Status is not specified.", PXErrorLevel.Error)
                : null);

        SaveAndExportBatchAction.SetEnabled(!(cache.Inserted.Cast<MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem>().Any(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.KiwiSaverStatus)) ||
                                              cache.Updated.Cast<MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem>().Any(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.KiwiSaverStatus))));

    }
```

This event raised only when selection changed, and **NOT** directly when I change the item in the Drop Down.  Means, to apply the change, user MUST change the selection.
All events I tried also raised after selection in the grid is changed. For instance:

```
public virtual void MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache,
        PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public virtual void MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache,
        PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected virtual void MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldVerifying(
        PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

My grid looks like this:

```
 <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" AutoAdjustColumns="True"
    Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="PrimaryInquire" TabIndex="100" AllowShowHide="Server" StatusField="ErrorMessage"
    AllowSearch="True" FastFilterFields="Surname,Firstname,IRDNumber" RestrictFields="True" SyncPosition="True">


    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="AllEmployeesTransactions" Key="IRBatchItemID">
            <RowTemplate>
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="Surname" runat="server" DataField="Surname" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="MiddleName" runat="server" DataField="MiddleName" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="EmployeeTitle" runat="server" DataField="EmployeeTitle" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="IRDNumber" runat="server" DataField="IRDNumber" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="BranchCD" runat="server" DataField="BranchCD" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="TaxCode" runat="server" DataField="TaxCode" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="EmployeeDOBDateTime1" runat="server" DataField="EmployeeDOBDateTime" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="EmployeeStartDate" runat="server" DataField="EmployeeStartDate" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="EmployeeEndDate" runat="server" DataField="EmployeeEndDate" />
                <px:PXDropDown ID="KiwiSaverStatus" runat="server"
                    DataField="KiwiSaverStatus"
                    CommitChanges="True" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" DataField="EmailAddress" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="MobilePhoneNumber" runat="server" DataField="MobilePhoneNumber" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="DaytimePhoneNumber" runat="server" DataField="DaytimePhoneNumber" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="Country" runat="server" DataField="Country" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="StreetName" runat="server" DataField="StreetName" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="City" runat="server" DataField="City" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="PostCode" runat="server" DataField="PostCode" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="State" runat="server" DataField="State" />
            </RowTemplate>
            <Columns>

                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Surname" LinkCommand="payDetailsAction" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Firstname" />

                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="MiddleName">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EmployeeTitle">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IRDNumber">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BranchCD">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TaxCode">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EmployeeDOBDateTime">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EmployeeStartDate">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EmployeeEndDate">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="KiwiSaverStatus"
                    Type="DropDownList"
                    CommitChanges="True">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EmailAddress">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="MobilePhoneNumber">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="DaytimePhoneNumber">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Country">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="StreetName">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="City">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="PostCode">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="State">
                </px:PXGridColumn>

            </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>

    <ActionBar ActionsText="False" DefaultAction="payDetailsAction">
        <Actions>
            <AddNew MenuVisible="false" ToolBarVisible="false"></AddNew>
            <Delete MenuVisible="false" ToolBarVisible="false"></Delete>
            <Refresh MenuVisible="False" ToolBarVisible="False"></Refresh>
        </Actions>
        <CustomItems>
            <px:PXToolBarButton Text="View Pay Details" Key="payDetailsAction" Tooltip="View pay details the currently selected employee" Visible="False">
                <AutoCallBack Command="PayDetailsAction" Target="ds">
                </AutoCallBack>
            </px:PXToolBarButton>
        </CustomItems>
    </ActionBar>
    <Mode AllowAddNew="false" AllowDelete="false" />
</px:PXGrid>
```

What do I need to do to inform my Graph that Record in the row has changed directly?
For instance in WPF we have UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"

I will be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. It does not causes to raise events directly after selection, but when you click on "Save & Export" button, cache already knows that this field was changed **without** changing the selection of the grid rows.
You need to define:

1. `SyncPosition="True"` in the datagrid
2. `[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]` in the button action implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you need SyncPosition="True" in your page PXGrid

Comment: I tried to add this property to the gird before posting, and it did not help, I added SyncPosition="True"  to the grid now to verify. It still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Did you get the FieldUpdating event to trigger? I see a mention to FieldUpdated but thats after the field change has made it to cache. FieldUpdating with SyncPosition = true should give you the event after the user changes the value but before the value makes it into cache.

Comment: I tried:
MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldUpdated
MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldUpdating
MPNewDepartingEmployeesBatchItem_KiwiSaverStatus_FieldVerifying
But all these events raised ONLY after selection on the gird was changed.

Comment: They should execute after the user changes the value. If you need to check or revert the value you can use the field verifying event or field updating event. You can set the value back to old value as needed

Comment: Maybe they should, but event raises ONLY AFTER selection in the data grid is changed.